# Navigation of URL in XML

Tags: xml, url

I am new to XML and I am trying to add a URL in XML data. I have seen below code from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<homepages xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <homepage xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</homepage>
  <homepage xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.w3.org">Visit W3C</homepage>
</homepages>
```

But in this code , I am not able to navigate. How can I create a hyperlink which when clicked in that XML will navigate to the respective webpage ?

Comment: XML is just data. You can express the information needed to create a hyperlink in lots of different ways (and xlink is one standardised way to do that), but it is up to the software reading the XML to actually create the hyperlink. We don't know what that software is, and you don't appear to be using a standard XML application (and you haven't specified a namespace for your homepages and homepage elemnets) so we can't tell you what you need to do.

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Please update your question by tagging it with the application you are using which will consume the XML.

Comment: i was editing in notepad and then viewing in IE only.

Answer (score -1):

Actually what you ask is related to HTML, which maybe XML, but is not necessarly wellformed XML. The a tag (<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>) refers to the anchor tag in HTML. But the use of it depends on the tooling that uses your xml document. XML enables you to define your own semantics.

With HTML a webbrowser knows what to do/how to interpret and act upon the tags. So you can see HTML as a variant or dialect of XML where more or less consensus is how to deal with for instance a  tag.

For XML this is not the case. XML is a structured way to work with data. An application/tooling can define what it does with that data. So unless your document is build up as HTML, you can't expect IE to know what to do with a link.

Comment: @Quentin At least you are consistent in downvoting people ^ ^.

Comment: There are plenty of things that use hyperlinks that aren't HTML. The question appears to be trying to use xlink.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But then I'm confused by the remark "..when clicked in that xml will navigate to the respective webpage ", which seems to relate to html-alike-use to me.

Comment: It's a very confusing question and the OP really needs to elaborate before it becomes reasonable to answer.

Comment: I suspect the real "answer" is going to be something like "What you are trying to do is not a good use for XML and won't make it easy to learn XML, use HTML for that instead".